# Скрытие элементов у всех JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как скрыть элемент у всех клиентов, если один из них нажмет допустим на элемент delete.

Вот начал писать:

```
$(function() {
    $(".delete").click(
        function() {
            var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
            // получаем значение элемента
            var commentId = $(this).attr("id");

            // Отправляем Ajax запрос методом POST, переменную id со значением commentId
            AjaxSuccess(commentContainer);              
            return false;
        }
    );
}); 

function AjaxSuccess(commentContainer) {
    // Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и обрабатываем их
    commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
}
```

Скрывает № элемента полученного из первой функции. Как сделать чтобы скрывалось у всех клиентов просматривающих страницу? Подскажите пожалуйста.

**UPD**

Как записать в память и передать это используя long poll?

Вот есть функция получения новых сообщений, в ней можно прочесть эту переменную и сделать скрытие?

```
function get_chat_messages () 
{   
    if ($('#block').val() == 'no') // если не выставлена блокировка повторного выполнения данной функции, продолжаем
    {
        $('#block').val('yes'); // ставим блокировку
        var last_act = $('#last_act').val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'func/chat_scripts.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 
            {
                'action': 'get_chat_message',
                'last_act': last_act
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) 
            {
                $('#block').val('no');

                $('#chat_text_field').append(result.message_code); // добавляем в текстовое поле новые сообщения
                $('#last_act').val(result.last_act); // обновляем значение последнего сообщения 
                // автопрокрутка текстового поля вниз
                $('#chat_text_field').scrollTop($('#chat_text_field').scrollTop()+100*$('.chat_post_my, .chat_post_other').size()); 



            } // конец success
        }); // конец ajax   
    }

}
```

Comment: Ну я так понимаю без БД не обойтись. Образно говоря это будет поле STATUS например. Т.е. принцип такой, тот кто нажал DELETE апдейтит поле STATUS в БД на значение "0", у остальных клиентов с некой переодичностью пусть каждую секу, дергается ajax запросом какой-нить серверный скрипт в котором вытягивается значение из поля STATUS, ну соответственно уже делаем скрыть или отобразить или что там надо.

Comment: Ну а реализацию или хоть начало реализации хоть можешь подкинуть? Просто в JS я не очень хорошо разбираюсь.

Comment: Я забыл уточнить что это скрипт простейшего чата. Так вот после извлечения последних 50-ти записей например скрипт должен вытягивать с каждого сообщения значение 0 или 1 и проверять уже ajax'ом если 0 то скрывать. в плане нагрузки и реализации это нормально? И не знаю как это написать JS, можно пример?

Comment: Не понял, каких 50-ти записей, по твоим объяснениям я понял так, ты хочешь по достижению больше чем 50 сообщений на экране, удалять последующуюю или что ты понимаешь под извлечением последних 50-ти? откуда они извлекаются? и что за записи? Уточняй, мы не телепаты, но помочь я думаю сможем :)

Comment: Последние записи после 50 скрыть не проблема, это же делается только на стороне клиента. У меня под каждым сообщением идет вот такого вида ссылка <a href="#" id="'.$sel_row['id'].'" class="delete">X</a>, после ее нажатия она скрывается вместе с сообщением, но только у того кто ее нажал, мне же нужно ее скрыть у всех пользователей. В дальнейшем она будет доступна только администратором естественно, так же собираюсь сделать и удаление из БД, но это не проблема. В данный момент ajax'ом подгружаются новые сообщения каждые 3 секунды, эту функцию я здесь писать не стал.

Comment: БД к черту. Самый лучший вариант - запись значения в память и последующее чтение этой записи. Можно реализовать как у vk - long poll.

Answer (score 1):

Короче как-то так, но не претендую на высший балл, надо еще допиливать, но может хотя бы на мысль наведу...

```
/* у того кто кликает */
$(function() {
    $(".delete").on(click, function(){
        $(this).load("update.php");
    } 
});

update.php
<?php
    // коннект к БД
    // запрос в БД на UPDATE поля STATUS значение равно "0"
?>

/* у того кто ждет что сейчас все исчезнет */
$(function() {
    $(".delete").everyTime(1000, function() {
        $(this).load("select.php");
    });
});

select.php
<?php
    // коннект к БД
    // запрос в БД на проверку значения STATUS, если "0", добавляем новое правило display: none
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотреть в сторону [Comet](http://javascript.ru/AJAX/COMET), [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), [WebSocket](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) и прочих подобных технологий